# Dim of $V$ from $V\otimes V$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

This is a bit of a simple question, but I'm just not sure of myself. If you have a rep $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ (finite dimensional for finite group), and you know $V\otimes V$ is an irrep, then is $V$ $1$D? By contradiction let the dimension be $n>1$; then the product would have dimension $n^2$ and $V\otimes \mathbb{C}$ would be a proper subspace (and proper subrep). Is this true?

Comment: I am confused, what is $V$? a representation, vector space, or what?

Comment: @JulianMejia V is the vector space, but I think it's common to refer to V as the representation itself when the hom is clear (or in this case, doesn't matter). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Your argument does not look correct: how does $V\otimes {\mathbb C}$ necessarily sit - as a $G$ module - in the tensor product? On the other hand, if there is a $G$-fixed vector $v$ in $V$, then one has  $V\otimes {\mathbb C}v \simeq  V\otimes {\mathbb C}$ as $G$-modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the representation $V$ is, the representation $V\otimes V$ splits
as the direct sum of the symmetric tensors and the alternating tensors.
The symmetric tensors are spanned by the $v\otimes w+w\otimes v$
and the alternating tensors by the $v\otimes w-w\otimes v$. If $\dim V=n$,
the symmetric and alternating tensors have dimensions $\frac12n(n+1)$ 
and $\frac12n(n-1)$ respectively. If $n\ge2$, both are non-trivial.

Comment: I didn't understand how $V\otimes\Bbb C$ was a subrepresentation of $V\otimes V$.

Comment: @user790924 if $V_i$ are $G$-invariant, then the tensor product is $G$-invariant.